# Does Swordmage Warding benefit a multiclassed wizard's summoned creatures?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, defense, swordmage

Okay, I looked around online and read both Forgotten Realms and Arcane Power, but am unclear on if Swordmage Warding benefits a Wizard's Summoned creatures.

I'm a wizard who has the Blade Initiate Swordmage multiclass feat because I wanted to use swords as implements as well as to have a method of doing better in melee combat while keeping a hand free to hold my Magic Tome (for the wizard Tome of Readiness class feature).

Do they also get the +1/+3 AC bonus? I know about them not getting temporary modifiers, but am unclear as to if SW counts as a temporary modifier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would count it as a temporary modifier.

> Benefit: You gain training in the Arcana skill.
>   Once per day, when you are wielding a blade, you can invoke the Swordmage Warding class feature as a minor action. Until the end of the encounter, you gain a +1 bonus to AC (or a +3 bonus to AC if you have one hand free). - Published in Forgotten Realms Player's Guide, page(s) 139.

Because you can only use it once per day and you have to invoke it as a minor action power vs. an always on class feature. The benefit is temporary just like an AC boost from any other power.